# An svg rect element shows up larger than its specified height and width when I apply an feTurbulence filter

Tags: svg

```html
<svg width='400' height='300' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filterGalv">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="27.4 49.7" seed='37.4' />
      <feColorMatrix type='saturate' values="0.05" />

    </filter>
    <filter id="filterWood">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.01 17.4" />
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 .31 .5
                                   0 0 0 .29 .3
                                   0 0 0 .28 .1
                                   0 0 0 0 1" />
    </filter>

    <mask id="cutoutMask">
      <rect x='160' y='140' width='80' height='50' fill="white" />
      <!--black is the default alpha channel-->
      <circle cx="200" cy="165" r="10" fill="black" />
    </mask>

  </defs>

  <rect x="20" y="140" width='360' height='50' filter="url(#filterWood)" />
  <rect x="160" y="140" width='80' height='50' mask="url(#cutoutMask)" fill="#efefef" />
  <rect x="160" y="140" width='80' height='50' mask="url(#cutoutMask)" filter="url(#filterGalv)" />

</svg>
```

The gray rectangle is correct size.  The brown rectangle should be the same height (50) and a shorter width.  It should start at x='20'.

I have tried changing everything to exact units (mm, px) but that only makes thigs worse.

Answer (score 2):

Filters are normally 10% larger than the element they filter (because using filters for drop shadows is so common). If you don't want that, just set the size to 100% (of the filtered element).

```html
<svg width='400' height='300' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filterGalv" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="27.4 49.7" seed='37.4' />
      <feColorMatrix type='saturate' values="0.05" />

    </filter>
    <filter id="filterWood" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.01 17.4" />
      <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 .31 .5
                                   0 0 0 .29 .3
                                   0 0 0 .28 .1
                                   0 0 0 0 1" />
    </filter>

    <mask id="cutoutMask">
      <rect x='160' y='140' width='80' height='50' fill="white" />
      <!--black is the default alpha channel-->
      <circle cx="200" cy="165" r="10" fill="black" />
    </mask>

  </defs>

  <rect x="20" y="140" width='360' height='50' filter="url(#filterWood)" />
  <rect x="160" y="140" width='80' height='50' mask="url(#cutoutMask)" fill="#efefef" />
  <rect x="160" y="140" width='80' height='50' mask="url(#cutoutMask)" filter="url(#filterGalv)" />

</svg>
```